# Could not find csv file located in the project?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, debugging, collections

I created a simple console project in Visual studio 2017 and looking to process a CSV file with LINQ. I generated csv file in Microsoft excel version 2019.

Here is Player.cs class code

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Debut { get; set; }
    public int Matches { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }


    //this is parsing of CSV file into Player object

    internal static Player ParseFromCsv(string line)
    {
        var columns = line.Split(',');
        return new Player
        {
            Name = columns[0],
            Country = columns[1],
            Debut = int.Parse(columns[2]),
            Matches = int.Parse(columns[3]),
            Average = double.Parse(columns[4])

        };
    }
```

Here is code inside the main method

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Processing a file
        var players = ProcessFile("player.csv");
        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{player.Name}\t{player.Debut}");
        }
    }

    private static List<Player> ProcessFile(string path)
    {

        var query = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
                    where line.Length > 1
                    select Player.ParseFromCsv(line);

                            return query.ToList();

    }
```

There is no compile time error but when I run the project it says Could not find csv file. However, I included the player.csv file in the project.

I googled to find any solution but none of them work. I called some of the people I know they said recreate the project, I did but same problem I faced.

Is there any help to solve the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your problem solved? @sageershaz

Comment: Yes Problem has been solved. But some other problems are posted looking for new solutions. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are hzving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is by right click on the "player.csv" file and click on properties. Once properties windows is open click on "Copy to output directory" and change the option into "Copy if newer". Make sure project is build before.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your error.

1. Insert full path in your code as following.

   **var players = ProcessFile("D:\work\solution\project\player.csv");**
2. Go to project properties window / Open Debug tab / Set Working directory.

   *player.csv* file must be in **Working** directory.